# Is `window.innerHeight` a calculated value?

Tags: javascript

## Background

I am trying to optimise my JavaScript buy making less calls to the DOM and use less computed values.

## Question

When using the value `window.innerHeight` is this calculated each time or is it coming from a an initial calculation?

## Example

Is this

```
let windowInnerHeight = window.innerHeight;
for (let value of values) {
  console.log(windowInnerHeight);
}
```

more performant than this

```
for (let value of values) {
  console.log(window.innerHeight);
}
```

Comment: What are you doing with `window.innerHeight`? Each access will [cause a relayout](https://gist.github.com/paulirish/5d52fb081b3570c81e3a) so it's best not to overuse it.

Comment: @torazaburo I was just looking at it in an abstract way. but relayout is actually the answer I was looking for. These kinds of performance drains that we can avoid by not recalculating each time. If you write an answer based on the relayout I will accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is generally poor practice to depend on `window.innerHeight`. Anything you want to do with it can usually be done better these days with media queries or other CSS, for example. If you must use `window.innerHeight`, use it only once, when necessary, because it triggers a potentially expensive reflow. See https://gist.github.com/paulirish/5d52fb081b3570c81e3a.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1, because window.innerHeight will fetch the current height of the window(updated value). So every time you will get the latest value when writing "window.innerHeight".

Comment: I think you're looking for the phrase "force re-layout".